# Django Admin Site Activation

Tags: python, django

I have been working on the Django tutorial and everything has gone perfect so far.

However in part 2, which teaches how to deal with the admin site, I encountered a problem.

After uncommenting the lines for activating the admin site [as told in the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial02/#activate-the-admin-site) I tried to activate the server and proceeded to the admin site to see the following error:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/
Site matching query does not exist
```

Well, with some googling I managed to resolve it by commenting the line in settings.py:

`'django.contrib.sites'`

Everything seemed to work fine after doing this, but I guess this is a problem since uncommenting this line is not mentioned in the tutorial

Django: 1.4.3

Python: 2.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncomment `django.contrib.sites` and run `syncdb` command. If you have already done that and it doesn't seem to work and you still want to leave `sites` app uncommented then:

Run `./manage.py shell`

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
Site.objects.create()
```

After that everything should be just fine. If you would like to modify the new Site record, you can do that in Django admin section `sites`.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks for the answer. Could you briefly explain why this happened?

Answer (score 0):

Python manage.py syncdb before runserver

Comment: Alright, I havent test django on MacOS, maybe something is wrong with your install.

Answer (score 0):

create a user if it is not done yet:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

add to the file settings.py:

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sites',
    ...
```

]

and in the bash run :

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and enjoy !